# Generating Multi level lists in Word with Bullets Using Officer in R

Tags: r, officer

I am trying to generate a MS Word document in R using the `officer` package. I found functions like `unordered_list` with `level_list` as an argument to generate unordered list of text for Powerpoint but not for Word. Any idea how can I recreate the following list paragraph in Word including these bullets?

[image]

Comment: This is not possible for now. This will certainly be implemented but not before few months.

Comment: @David Gohel thanks. Look forward to having this functionality. In the meantime do you think it's possible to achieve this in R maybe through R Markdown?

Comment: @DavidGohel Are there still plans to implement the creation of numbered and/or bulleted lists in Word using ‘officer’? If not, then are there any known/suggested workarounds? Having the ability to add lists would be an excellent feature (for what is already an extremely useful package!).